# I Don't know how I can I make my kitchen sink drain down pipe intersect with the "p" trap?

Tags: kitchens, drain

I have replaced my kitchen counter top and sink, The new drain is in a different position. The drain down pipe does not run into the "p" trap at a straight vertical, no matter what I do with the other elbows and pipes it is just not able to connect properly and maintain a straight vertical. I am temporarily using a flex down pipe, its not at all a permanent solution.
What can I do?

[image]

Comment: You'll need to phrase something as a question in order to get an answer ...

Comment: Can you [include a photo](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/524/33) or two?

Comment: I'll load a pic this evening.

Comment: Sorry for the pics 90" degree offset, was upright prior to the upload.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to install a new P-trap. Cut it off past the trap and then re-plumb in the correct spot. You may be able to use the old P-trap depending on where you need to cut, how it's glued, etc, but without a picture that's impossible to judge.

Be sure when you cut it that you'll be able to get a new fitting on the end, that usually means at least 3/4" pipe sticking out into the cabinet space.

Dry fit the entire assembly first, including the tailpiece to the sink, and only glue it once it's all in place.

There are P-traps with unions on one end that can help if the fit is tight, and regular unions (or slipnuts) are also sometimes necessary.

[image]

Comment: If I could bend my own an inch larger in diameter that would end this saga.

Comment: I've considered using two elbows with a straight to join them at the correct length but I would only do that if I could find those fittings in a glue-able form,  Home Depot only carry's compression nut type.

Comment: @GreggO - In all of the Home Depots I've been to, the glue-able fittings are usually with the 10' lengths of pipe 1 or 2 aisles down from the aisle where the P-traps with compression fittings are.